# PHP How to find out the filesize on an array for memcached

Tags: php, mysql, memcached

From what i have read, you can not store values or data over 1mb at a time with memcached. If this is the case, is there any way to find out the filesize of an array before submitting it to memcached?

Comment: what do you mean by filesize of an array?

Comment: I assume the op just means 'size of the array'... 'cause filesize does indeed make no sense in this context.

Comment: what compression level you have been use?

Comment: As far as im aware im not using any compression at the moment, im just playing around with memcached and getting to grips with it at the moment, as i may need it on future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcache is a key/value store, and hence does not 'know' about more *"complex"* objects. What the module does is serialize the value & store that as a string. So, the total size = `strlen(serialize($value));` Note that your want the [**non**-overloaded version of `strlen`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php)!

Comment: Thank you Wrikken! I never knew about the 'Function Overloading', what are the pro's / con's of using the overloaded versions of these functions?

Comment: The overloaded methods are usefull for utf8 strings especially. The thing is, it stores each character in 3 times more space that the classical strlen. Just try this snippet : `var_export(strlen('ï').' !== '.mb_strlen('ï'));`. Memcache does not use those mb_* functions to using them will give you a false result ;)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, however you can change the 1MB limit to something larger if needed.

See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached

> -I  Override the default size of each slab page. Default is 1mb. Default is 1m, minimum is 1k, max is 128m. Adjusting this value
>   changes the item size limit. Beware that this also increases the
>   number of slabs (use -v to view), and the overal memory usage of
>   memcached.

You can also enable compression to reduce the size of the value as well. See: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/memcache.setcompressthreshold.php

Answer (score -1):

Or you try a complicated way `strlen(serialize($array));`
Or you try the easy way

```
$before = memory_get_usage();
$myarray = array(<content>);
$size = memory_get_usage() - $before;
```

Could not think of any other way sorry

Comment: And what happens if GC happens between the `memory_get_usage()` calls?

Comment: Thanks for the tip korko, that's a usefull snippet to know about, but if memcached stores data as a serialized string, and considering the memcached server could be on an external machine, i think the strlen(serialize($array)); method is better for what i am trying to achive.

Comment: GC is the Garbage Collector. It's a system that will remove all unused variables and stuff in the memory to clean up. It's important to know that in PHP, the GC is almost never called. It needs at least 10,000 (GC_ROOT_BUFFER_MAX_ENTRIES) variables used at a time. Take a look at the doc (http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.collecting-cycles.php). It's almost impossible for the GC to run here.

Comment: @korko Thanks for explaining garbage collection. Wrt to your post, you can remedy this by turning garbage collection off (via `gc_disable()` or some other mechanism).